# How to connect to SQL Server using Azure Active Directory Credentials?

Tags: sql-server, azure, alteryx

I have a difficulties regarding making a connection to SQL Server using Input Data Tools in Alteryx.

So, i'm using a Azure Active Directory for the credentials login in the Azure SQL Database using Authentication mode : Active Directory - Password. I already tested it out the related user and working just fine.

The problem is, in Alteryx i want to connect to my data in the Azure SQL Database. What the options provided is, you need to insert either Windows or SQL Authentication. As im using an AAD, i cannot access my data.

There are several things that i tried, like using the SQL Authentication and append my ID with the servername, still failed.

I'm thinking of is there any way to connect my AAD credential to SQL authentication? like i'm creating a login ( CREATE LOGIN ) but for the password still related to the AAD user (I create the user using CREATE USER FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER) .

Any Input or information will be extremely helpful.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't any way to connect your AAD credential to SQL Authentication

Alteryx need to update their driver to support `Active Directory - Password`

In the meantime you'll need to use SQL Authentication

You'll need to create a SQL User / password in SQL Azure in the database with this:

```
CREATE USER UserName WITH PASSWORD = '<password>';
```

Also remember that you *must* designate a database when connecting

TBH there is not a lot of difference between the two from the client side. In both cases you still need to designate a user name and password on the client side.

As per Mitch Wheat's comment: Make sure your connection is encrypted so that login/pwd is not passed over the network in clear text

I suggest that you stay in the habit of using AAD authentication where possible and only use the SQL credentials when using Alteryx

Comment: If you use Username/password to remote server you should encrypt connections.

Comment: Hi Nick, i take it that the newly created user will not having any relationship with the AAD credentials i have setup previously in the Azure SQL Server ? So the end result:  the user can login in the SSMS either using SQL Authentication or AD-Password (They have now 2 different credentials), which for SQL temporarily used for the Alteryx Designer side.

Comment: Yes that's right. I suggest you use the SQL credentials _only_ for Alteryx - don't mix and match. Unfortunately there is limited support (even from Microsoft) for AAD authentication.

Comment: I see... for now, i'll see if others have other input for this. Thanks a lot Nick and Mitch! Maybe i'll try to setup a new login for now

Comment: He's right, Windows Authentication will not work for an AAD authentication to Azure SQL. I'd log a ticket with Alteryx and request they add support for this authentication method. It's a minor change to the connection string.